# Django manytomany: get all elements of all sets

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I've got two models that are relevant here; `Item` and `Category`, and they look as follows:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to create a page that lists all `Categories` and their respective `Items`. I realise I can just iterate over `Category.objects.all()` and retrieve `.items.all()` for each of those instances, but that seems terribly inefficient. Is there not a way to do this in a constant number of queries rather than one that scales with the number of categories? I envision the result to be some sort of 2D data structure of `Categories` containing `Items` that I can then iterate over in my template in a nested loop.

I've seen questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816653/how-to-get-list-of-objects-involving-many-to-many-relation-in-django) that deal with a similar problem, but those typically revolve around some `Item` instance that they wish to look up (which, indeed, can be done in a constant number of queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) does.

In fact, that gives you a queryset, but with the `.items.all()` pre-populated.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. The example is nearly identical to my situation. Thanks!